# File drag event in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, windows-explorer

Is it possible to detect `file drag action`(event?) in `Windows Explorer` or on the desktop from the `C# Windows Service`?

Comment: You can try to subscribe on DISPID_BEGINDRAG event in every Windows Explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use events provided by the `static` class `HookManager`. Note that the sender object in events is always `null`. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C).